# Navigation Drawer - Alterar cor menu

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

Olá, estou implementando um navigation drawer em minha aplicação android e por uma questao de design gostaria de saber como alterar a cor de fundo do activity_home_drawer, local onde se encontra os itens do menu?

Comment: O que você tentou?

Answer (score 1):

vai no xml da sua principal activity!

```
   design.widget.NavigationView


    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:itemTextColor="#f8f7fc"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#7CFC00" (aqui muda o cor)
    app:itemIconTint="#f8f7fc"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer"/>
```

Comment: Não falta o `<` no inicio da etiqueta de `NavigationView` ?

Comment: Sim. Más esse é para lembra-lo em qual parte do código deve ser aplicada a mudança de cor.